# not able to iterate through array of arrays in javascript - something wrong with parent array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I created an array of arrays from an api call. The parent array is arrStories. When I display the parent array in console.log, it looks like this:

```
[]
```

When I click the little arrow next to `[]` I get all the child arrays. They each look similar to this:

```
0: Array(4)
0: "08 Apr 2019"
1: "Avoiding those surprise bills when you stumble out of your insurance network"
2: "https://url"
3: "https://url-of-image"
length: 4
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

When I try to get the length of the parent array, though:

```
console.log(arrStories.length); //returns 0
```

What has happened??

Here is how I filled my arrays:

```js
$.getJSON('my-api', function(data) {
  getStories(data); //push stories into an array of arrays
});

orderStories(arrStories); //order by date descending

function getStories(data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.articles.length; i++) {
    var pubDate = data.articles[i].publishedDate;
    pubDate = pubDate.slice(5);
    pubDate = pubDate.substring(0, pubDate.length - 15);
    arrStory.push(pubDate, data.articles[i].title, data.articles[i].link, data.articles[i].images[0].url); //push values into array
    arrStories.push(arrStory); //push array into parent array
    arrStory = []; //clear original array
  }
}

function orderStories(arrStories) {
  arrStories.sort(function(a, b) {
    var dateA = new Date(a.date),
      dateB = new Date(b.date)
    return dateA - dateB;
  });
}
```

Comment: Please change your code to a [mcve] with an example object - I made you a snippet. Change `$.getJSON('my-api', function(data) {
  getStories(data); //push stories into an array of arrays
});` to an example instead

Comment: asynchronous requests 101 You order a pizza and you try to eat it before it is made and delievered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's an issue of your `$.getJSON` callback happening **after** you're synchronously calling `orderStories` on the next line -- I think you want to put orderStories in the `$.getJSON` callback

I think you're ordering the stories before you've received them

Another approach could look something like this

```
async function getData () {
  return new Promise(resolve =>  { $.getJSON('my-api', resolve) };
}

getData().then(data => {
  const stories = getStories(data);
  const orderedStories = getOrderedStories(stories);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have an object with .date and you need to process all inside the getJSON function

You likely want this

```js
function getStories(data) {
  return data.map(article => {
    var pubDate = data.articles[i].publishedDate;
    pubDate = pubDate.slice(5);
    pubDate = pubDate.substring(0, pubDate.length - 15);
    return {
      date: pubDate,
      title: article.title,
      link: article.link,
      imageUrl: article.images[0].url
    }
  })
}


function orderStories(arrStories) {
  arrStories.sort(function(a, b) {
    var dateA = new Date(a.date),
      dateB = new Date(b.date)
    return dateA - dateB;
  });
}
$.getJSON('my-api', function(data) {
  const arrStories = getStories(data)
  orderStories(arrStories)
  // here you can process arrStories
});
```

Comment: I get the message "Uncaught TypeError: data.map is not a function".

Comment: @LauraNMS I need to post an example object so I can fix my code to work with your data